# Gnome 3 "broken" after upgrades, kind of looks like gnome 2 . . .?

Tags: debian, gnome3, troubleshooting

I'm running debian wheezy ( testing ) and after some upgrades my gnome 3 is broken.  It's not exactly broken, but it's completey different.  Almost like it's no longer actually gnome 3; most of the UI bells and whistles are gone and it mostly look like gnome 2.

Anyway, how does one start troubleshooting such a thing?  I looked in /var/log/gdm3 and didn't see any glaring errors; I did see some minor errors but they seem to be in the older logs too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me this sounds most likely that your graphics card drivers are not installed correctly. Could this be a possibility ?

Because then GNOME would start in "Fallback mode" which looks most likely like Gnome2.

Check /var/log/gdm3/:0.log and /var/log/Xorg.0.log for errors, particularly stemming from the graphics card driver.

Comment: This is good info.  I believe it is fallback mode, though I'll have to verify that.  I did see some complaints about my nvidia driver in the logs, but those seem to be in much older logs too . . .  I'll do some more looking.  Thanks.

Comment: So, I looked in those logs ;) and I found out that my GLX support was broken in my proprietary NVIDIA driver.  I reinstalled the very same version of the driver, and it works.  I suppose some dependency of the NVIDIA driver changed, and it needed to be reinstalled; I guess being installed by the binary installer doesn't allow for awareness of shifting dependencies, as would be the case if the thing was installed via the debian package management system.

Comment: glad it helped - I had the similar problems when upgrading to Gnome3, so I thought this must be the most likely case. I saw in GDM (the login manager) that it started Gnome3 fallback mode and not the normal Gnome3 session.

Comment: The problem solves by reinstalling a video card driver. To me the fastest solution was using sgfxi script.